# PHP echo format inside other variables

Tags: php, html, variables, format, echo

I've been trying to echo other variables inside a variable. I read other questions and pages about using ' and . to properly format in multiple different ways, but it only parsed some of them correctly.

From what I read, `'.$var.''.$var2.'` should have worked, then I tried `'$var . $var2'`, `'$var' . '$var2'`, and a few others. All returned errors.

PHP:

```
<?php
$path = "/img/";
$file = "photo.jpg";
$width = "300";
$height = "250";
$x = "<span class=\"showthis\" style=\"background-image: url($path $file); width: $width px; height: $height px\"></span>";
?>
```

I'm trying to understand how to format it in order to have two variables directly beside each other to parse without spaces.

```
<?php echo $x; ?>
```

as:

```
<span class="showthis" style="background-image: url(/img/photo.jpg); width: 300px; height: 250px;"></span>
```

I guess my question specifically, would be how to have two variables consecutively without spaces in them parsing.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use braces to show that its a variable, and you can then put them next to each other

```
$x = "<span class=\"showthis\" style=\"background-image: url({$path}{$file}); width: $width px; height: $height px\"></span>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In general you have to use `.` between two string to "add" them
it must be look like this :

```
$x = "<span class=\"showthis\" style=\"background-image: url(".$path.$file."); width: ".$width." px; height: ".$height." px\"></span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can simply remove the space.

```
$x = "<span class=\"showthis\" style=\"background-image: url($path $file); width: $width px; height: $height px\"></span>";
```

becomes

```
$x = "<span class=\"showthis\" style=\"background-image: url($path$file); width: $width px; height: $height px\"></span>";
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to work either. And in the case of $width or $height before px, I didn't know how to separate them without px being read as being part of the variable.

Comment: In that case, bizzehdee has the solution: use braces.

Comment: Although, it should work: [http://3v4l.org/rSiY3](http://3v4l.org/rSiY3). Your problem might be somewhere else.